# What can be done to popularize codereview.stackexchange.com

Tags: discussion

I am a big fan of codereview.stackexchange.com. There is a lot to learn but unfortunately the site is not as popular as stackoverflow and  programmers.stackexchange.com.

Many questions are migrated from stackoverflow and  programmers.stackexchange.com. What can be done to popularize the site and make it first stop for code reviews.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**StackOverflow & Programmers**

Browse questions on StackOverflow & Programmers and aks to migrate here, if they better fit Code Review. People over there will start noticing soon and hopefully will come here when in need of code reviews.

If you find questions that parts of them may fit Code Review, leave a comment suggesting that the op could ask here on those parts specifically.

**Social networks**

Share questions on some social network and / or news aggregators like Reddit or Digg. Pick questions that you think best define the scope of Code Review.

**Improve the content**

This is the single most important thing any one of us can do, especially since Code Review is in its beta phase. My first impression of the site was that it was a big mess. The first 10 or so questions I happened upon had several problems:

- None or extremely bad code formatting
- Clearly outside of the scope of the site
- Poor syntax & grammar
- Very large code blocks
- Code blocks that didn't actually work

When I revisited the site, I immediately got the impression that the Code Review community was actively addressing those issues, and that was enough to make me visit every couple of days, contribute a question, an answer and a few votes. Nothing special really, most of my free time goes to Programmers.

But I like it here, so I'll try to spend some time:

- Editing questions
- Retagging questions
- Flagging questions
- Voting up and down on questions and answers
- Commenting everywhere (I'm chatty and open-ended)
- Suggesting improvements on meta

Obviously all of the above are helpful for any Stack Exchange site, but are extremely critical for beta sites where the community is small and the rewards are slow.